# the best way to make a gallery page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Just wondering if someone could tell me the best way to make a gallery page, cos at the moment I'm using images inside the html and as the page and images are getting more the page takes for ever to load, so I'd really appreciate it if you could tell the practice regarding different galleries on one page.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Galleriffic is a jQuery plugin that provides a rich, post-back free experience optimized to handle high volumes of photos while conserving bandwidth

http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/

Answer (score 1):

I used fancybox and it's really easy, ready to use and good looking.

http://fancybox.net/

Answer (score 0):

Probably the slowest thing is how long it takes to download the image files (they're much bigger than a normal .html file).

So, make sure you're using thumbnails correctly. Have two different versions of each image: one file with the full-size image and one much smaller image file with the thumbnail. In your gallery page just show the thumbnails, and maybe one full-size image at a time - so your users aren't waiting for all the full-size images to download at once.